# nginx mysteriously stops serving requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I'm trying to deploy a Rails app to an EC2 instance.

I can't quite get nginx + Rails to the point where my Rails app can be served.

I've been encountering some errors related to permissions. Sometimes, when I make some permissions change (e.g. `sudo chown -R ubuntu .` in the Rails project directory) and then restart nginx, nginx completely stops working and I get a "This site can’t be reached" error in Chrome. Once I reach that point it seems there's nothing I can do to get nginx working again.

How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: We have a similar issue where during ITs the nginx deployed in docker on some CI system stops serving requests, no access.log or error.log content is written, nginx still accepts connections (but that could also be the docker proxy) but no response is given anymore. when killing nginx all the running request are written to the access log. nginx versions tested 1.15.10 and 1.18.0 and 1.19.10. does anybody know how to troubleshoot nginx if its not responding?